# `git log` output not the same as input date format

Tags: git, date

Here is my `git log` command:

```
git log --no-merges --date=format:'%Y-%m-%d' --format=format:'%C(bold blue)%h%C(reset) %C(green)%cD%C(reset) %C(cyan)%an%C(reset) %sd'
```

Here is the output:

```
b4d6b7b8c Wed, 24 Aug 2022 19:31:20 -0700 FirstName1 LastName1 Sample subject 1
14d2b9170 Wed, 24 Aug 2022 19:23:12 -0700 FirstName2 LastName2 Sample subject 2
8c4fda8b2 Wed, 24 Aug 2022 18:53:54 -0700 FirstName3 LastName3 Sample subject 3
...
```

I was expecting dates to be in `2022-08-24` format in the output.

I read the Git documentation, particularly the `--date` options. What mistake am I doing? Does it have to do with committer date (`%cD`) cannot be changed to the format I requested?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the placeholder `%cd` instead of `%cD`.

> %cd
>
> committer date (format respects --date= option)
>
> %cD
>
> committer date, RFC2822 style

Reference: https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt-emcdem